# Magento 2: Abstract Controller class is not being override

Tags: magento2, overrides, admin-controller, abstract-class

**I am trying to override an abstract class `vendor/magento/module-sales/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/Create.php` using `di.xml` but it is not working.** 
I need to do some changes in method **`protected function _processActionData($action = null)`**.

> /vendor/magento/module-sales/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/Create.php

```
namespace Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order;
   abstract class Create extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
   {
      protected function _processActionData($action = null)
      { ....
      }
```

> /app/code/CustomAPI/Product/etc/di.xml

```
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Create" type="CustomAPI\Product\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Create" />
</config>
```

> /app/code/CustomAPI/Product/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/Create.php

```
 namespace CustomAPI\Product\Controller\Adminhtml\Order

     class Create extends Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Create
     {
```

Comment: YOu cannot  override Abstract class

Comment: why you don't use  event `$this->_eventManager->dispatch('adminhtml_sales_order_create_process_data_before', $eventData);`

Comment: @AmitBera Could you Please tell me that how can I make changes in this function protected function _processActionData($action = null)

Comment: what changes you want inside on `_processActionData`

Comment: I have added a custom discount check box on admin create order page. Then I need to perform an event on **update Item and quantities**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in this case `adminhtml_sales_order_create_process_item_before` is best  events.

At this event you can get

```
    $eventData = [
        'order_create_model' => $this->_getOrderCreateModel(),
        'request_model' => $this->getRequest(),
        'session' => $this->_getSession(),
    ];
```

Request params using  `$observer->getRequestModel()`.

and  order create model  using `$observer->getOrderCreateModel()`.

and Session using `$observer->getSession()`.

When `update Item and quantities` button hit then a param send to request `update_items`.

And  `update_items` param only posted when we click on `update Item and quantities`. That means you put it as a condition on observer.

### Observer class:

```
<?php

namespace Devbera\TestPractics\Obsever;

class UpdateItems implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $request = $observer->getEvent()->getRequestModel();
        $orderCreateModel = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderCreateModel();
        
        if($request->getPost('update_items')){
            // Perform operation on 
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks It is working. Now I need to call **protected function _processFiles($items)** in observer. Could you please tell me how do I use it.

Comment: Might you use `adminhtml_sales_order_create_process_item_before` and it give same parameters. changes request item `$this->getRequest()->getPost('item')` details .Like `$this->getRequest()->setPost('item', $yourparam)`

Comment: I need to run same these functions in observer also
`if ($this->getRequest()->getPost('update_items')) {
            $items = $this->getRequest()->getPost('item', []);
            $items = $this->_processFiles($items);
            $this->_getOrderCreateModel()->updateQuoteItems($items);
        }`

but I am unable to call `$this->_processFiles($items)` and `$this->_getOrderCreateModel()->updateQuoteItems($items)` in observer

Comment: I am facing this error **Invalid method Magento\Sales\Model\AdminOrder\Create::_processFiles**

Comment: `this->_processFiles($items)` you could not like this way.You can  changes the params of `items`